# How to select 1 item in a slicer

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

I need your expertise in vba. I have this code which I copied from one of my macros:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Export_Country").VisibleSlicerItemsList = _
    Array( _
    "[Table2].[Export Country].&[IN]")
```

This basically selects the value in a slicer based on the value you declared (i.e. "IN")

But when I tried using this code in my other macros, it returns with the error: "Application-defined or user-defined error".

I found out that the Table2 in the code was created on the file where it is used for so I made my own table which I named Table1. I modified it based on my needs:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Departure_Country").VisibleSlicerItemsList = _
    Array( _
    "[Table1].[Departure Country].&[AU]")
```

But still it returns the same error.

Thank you!

Comment: Regular table, or pivot table?  Have you tried recording a macro while making the selection in your new table?  What does the code produced look like?

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi! I'm not sure what you meant by regular table or pivot table? Is it somehow related to the macro? Yes, I tried and it looked like this

Comment: With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Departure_Country")
        .SlicerItems("AU").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("CN").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("HK").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("ID").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("JP").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("KR").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("PH").Selected = False

Comment: The problem with my recorded macro code is that it also deselects the other values in the slicer. What I only need is to select the value. Is it possible?

Comment: Is your slicer enabled for "multi-select" ?  Can you share an example workbook? Your posted code looks like you have a cube (?) whereas I'm just using a simple table... You can at least post an example of the recorded code from your current table.